# A link generated from the web site does not open in my app but same link genrated from app its work properly

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter

In my android app code Manifest file contains following Intent filter for handling a Link in the app but doesn't work

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="safimoney.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/.*/transactions/request-money/confirm/.*" />

</intent-filter>
```

test it with link generated from web "https://safimoney.com/en/transactions/request-money/confirm/0CnpXE7u5hXRD1JVcZM2APHcYElKZvBZs8GeqimJ" but it doesn't ask for an open link in the app.

Comment: try `pathPattern` instead of `android:pathPrefix` i am not sure but give it a try . Read about [data tags](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html).

Comment: I will test already with  path pattern bt does not work

Comment: @NikitaJain maybe you can try Firebase dynamic link solution https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/?authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to open a link, use below code.

---

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

---

It will ask to select browser while opening this link.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna do a Deep Link, right?

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="open"
        android:scheme="companyName" />
    <data
        android:host="companywebsite.com"
        android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I would suggest for you take a look in [Branch.io](https://bnc.lt/m/iCEBx5TVLK) for link-app solutions.

But if you wanna make a webView inside your app [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) can help you.
This is one of the cases where developer.android website has everything that you need, even code examples. Just need to ready with a lot of attention. Hope it helps

**EDIT**
About your data, looking on [android developer website](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html), this should be the better way to set:

```
<data
    android:scheme="https"
    android:host="safimoney.com"
    android:pathPrefix="/en/transactions/request-money/confirm/" />
```

But even after this you should add a data like this

```
<data android:scheme="safimoney"
          android:host="/en/transactions/request-money/confirm/" />
```

Comment: Yaa it's a deep link.but tell me in my code which mistakes does not open the link in app

Comment: @NikitaJain Ok, first let use the same words ahahahah is not "open the link in app" should be "Link to open the app" make sense? Look my edit, but I would suggest again to use Branch.io is a great solution.

Comment: thanx for the comment, but it doesn't work. I think I have a small mistake. which cannot find them.

Comment: but one doubt in my mind is that  it works properly for same Link test throw "android link assistant" in the tools menu .but does not work the same link directly click on a link

Comment: @NikitaJain I cannot now exactly what you mean to help you. But you put the other answer as right. So is already solved, no?

Comment: in chrome browser, a link copy from Flipkart site than the pest on hangout ya other social media.but on the phone has a Flipkart app than click on a link from hangout. it firstly moves on chrome than redirect to the app. same functionality adds in-app.

how can do that?

Comment: My issue is 2nd Scenario in Link "http://myandroidtuts.blogspot.in/2013/07/custom-url-scheme-in-android.html" but again a doubt is how to Add  "website just add an anchor tag with the link"

Comment: @NikitaJain I wanna help you, but you already put the "right mark" in another answer. So the question is solved, right? If you have more questions just need to create another question to people help ˆˆ

Comment: Now, un-except the answer. by mistake, the question is right tick mark. but it is not my answer. please guide if u have a solution for that

Comment: @NikitaJain ok, let's see.
You question about A link that open chrome than open the app is already answered in my answer. It is a Deep link, you need to make the configurations that I told you and has examples in Android Developer Website. But I would like to remember that this will be easy using the branch.io solution, that I give to you in the answer. If you have any new question I will be happy to help.